# Is there any way to show an input when string introduced in the datalist it is not in the datalist?

Tags: html, css, input, html-datalist

I have never use a datalist and I want to show file type input only when the value that it´s written is not in the datalist. This is my code:

```
<input list="customer" name="customer">
  <datalist id="customer">
    <option value="Customer 1">
    <option value="Customer 2">
    <option value="Customer 3">
  </datalist>
<input type="file">
```

So, what I want is that if you introduce a value that is not in the option, I want to show the input type file. Is it any way to do it with CSS?

EDIT: I have changed the code because the options that I want to show are in a php array. So this is my code now:

```
<datalist id="customer">
  <?php
   foreach ($_SESSION[CUSTOMER_NAMES] as $row) {
     ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    </datalist>
    <div class="inputBox">
       <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" required="" list="customer"
       <?php 
         if (isset($_SESSION[CUSTOMER])) { 
           ?> 
           value="<?php echo $_SESSION[CUSTOMER]; ?>" 
       <?php } ?>>
       <label for="customer">Customer</label>                    
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in CSS only it's not possible, I would use javascript and I'd create an array of option values; on `input` event I would check if the value exists in the array.

If a value is retrieved a `.found` class is toggled in the list input and then the file input can be hidden using a sibling selector

```js
var dl = [...document.querySelectorAll('option')].map(
            (opt) => opt.value);

var cs = document.querySelector('[name="customer"]');

cs.addEventListener('input', function() {
   this.classList.toggle('found', dl.includes(this.value))   
});
```

```css
[type="file"] { display: inline-block; }
.found ~ [type="file"] { display: none; }
```

```html
<input list="customer" name="customer">
  <datalist id="customer">
    <option value="Customer 1">
    <option value="Customer 2">
    <option value="Customer 3">
  </datalist>
  
<input type="file">
```

Comment: I have tried to put this in my code but it´s not working for me.  I have update it, can you check it?

Comment: I can't check server side code. you need to return the same markup you posted